# How to read a text file to find a value using a function built in python

Tags: python

I have a function that reads in a list. it will iterate through the list and use that as the function input. It reads a text file that only contains 2  lines.

> LC1
>   LC2

```
import re

def dict(input):
    for line in file:
        if re.search(input,line):
            print(input)
            d[input]=None
        else:
            print(d)
            break




file = open("Text.txt",'r')
d={}
kw=['LC1','LC2']
for input in kw:
    dict(input)
```

When it inputs **LC2** the function break right away and I'm not sure why.The end goal is to have a dictionary that looks like this

> d={LC1:None,LC2:None}

Comment: Remove the `else` part. If you do not find the input in the first line you are breaking the loop.

Comment: Hello! Be careful - `dict` is already the name of a default python class (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict ) so it may be unwise to replace it...

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(open("Text.txt",'r'))` i would think is enough

Comment: @Anon also `input`

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do it:

```
def todict(vals,file):
    d={}
    for line in file:
        if line.rstrip() in vals:
            d[line.rstrip()]=None

    return d

file = open("Text.txt",'r')
print(todict(['LC1','LC2'],file))
```

But still the easiest way is:

```
def todict(vals,file):
    return {}.fromkeys([i.rstrip() for i in file if i.rstrip() in vals])

file = open("Text.txt",'r')
print(todict(['LC1','LC2'],file))
```

Both reproduce:

```
{'LC1': None, 'LC2': None}
```